# Searching for a specific name pattern in a column

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I have the next question. How do I use the wildcart '%' in sybase ? I've trying to create a store procedure to get information like employee names that contain a specific letter OR a pattern, for example a 'C' but when I run the script I only get records which last letter is C. I've done some test like selecting the parameter to see whats receiving and I noticed that when I set a varible with the parameter, the code only puts a wildcart % at the beginning of the string, example:

> PARAMETER c
>
> VARIABLE %c
>
> Name FREDIC ISAAC

Here's my code

```
USE AD06RECHUMBD_DESA
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO

IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.pr_EmpleadoPrueba') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.pr_EmpleadoPrueba
GO

USE AD06RECHUMBD_DESA

GO
SET ANSINULL ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].pr_EmpleadoPrueba(
     @pNOMBRE CHAR (20)
)

AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @NOMBRE CHAR (20)
    SET @NOMBRE = '%' + @pNOMBRE + '%'
    SELECT @pNOMBRE AS PARAMETER
    SELECT @NOMBRE AS VARIABLE


        SELECT      A.DES_NOMBRE AS Nombre

        FROM        RH_EMPLEADO A

        WHERE       A.DES_NOMBRE LIKE UPPER(@NOMBRE)

        ORDER BY    A.DES_NOMBRE

END
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.pr_EmpleadoPrueba TO user_sirhportal
GO

COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO
```

What could be the main reason?

Comment: Try using VARCHAR instead of CHAR. CHAR pads characters with spaces.

Comment: Else you can change your query. Try to add the % with query rahter than already doing it with the declaration